# Shopify Add to Cart button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Something's up with my form but I can't fix it, the button doesn't add an item when it has a selector, in this case grip tape. See link here which demonstrates [link](https://www.thelowendstore.com/collections/decks/products/chocolate-transportation-stevie-perez-8-0?properties[Griptape%3F]=Grip%20it%20for%20me&id=10318485443&quantity=1&add=):

```html
 <form 
                <p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label>Griptape?</label><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="properties[Griptape?]" value="Grip it for me"> <span>Grip it for me</span><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="properties[Griptape?]" value="Just send the grip"> <span>Just send the grip</span><br>
</p>
                <action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm">
            <select name="id" id="productSelect" class="product-single__variants">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.available %}

                  <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>

                {% else %}
                  <option disabled="disabled">
                    {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                  </option>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <div class="product-single__quantity{% unless settings.product_quantity_enable %} is-hidden{% endunless %}">
              <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
              <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn">
              <span id="AddToCartText">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
            </button>
          </form>
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. For anyone in future, this is the corrected code:

```html
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm">
                <p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label>Griptape?</label><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="properties[Griptape?]" value="Grip it for me"> <span>Grip it for me</span><br>
  <input required class="required" type="radio" name="properties[Griptape?]" value="Just send the grip"> <span>Just send the grip</span><br>
</p>

            <select name="id" id="productSelect" class="product-single__variants">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.available %}

                  <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>

                {% else %}
                  <option disabled="disabled">
                    {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                  </option>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <div class="product-single__quantity{% unless settings.product_quantity_enable %} is-hidden{% endunless %}">
              <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
              <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn">
              <span id="AddToCartText">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
            </button>
          </form>
```